# Classes on list items with GWCode Categories

Tags: categories, gwcode-categories

I've just started using GWCode Categories for the first time, and have seen it oft-cited as a go-to solution here.

I need to rely on nested output for navigation, but I need classes on the `<li>` (similar to Structure's output). I see that there are variables to check for "has children" and I could compare cat_url_title to my segment vars to get the "here" status, but I don't see a way to get those onto the `<li>`.

Are those sorts of classes supported on the `<li>` and I'm missing something? Or is there a way to get nested output and write my own `<li>` tags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter style="linear" and can out the

according to your preference. Take a reference from this example at the add-on website:
http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/examples/example11

Comment: Ah, so the `depth` tags are used in `linear` style to build the nested output with custom markup. I'll take a look & report back. Thanks!