# GWCode Categories - Custom UL code

Tags: gwcode-categories, nested-list, custom-classes

I'm struggling with this question again: [Classes on list items with GWCode Categories](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6014/classes-on-list-items-with-gwcode-categories)[Classes on list items with GWCode Categories](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6014/classes-on-list-items-with-gwcode-categories)

I'm trying to generate an unordered list with custom classes on the list items (for expand/collapse hooks). The problem I'm having is when it goes from depth3 to depth1.

```
depth1 item
-- depth2 item
---- depth3 item
-- depth2 item (works fine!)
---- depth3 item
depth1 item (depth3_end can't just trigger one level of closing UL; how to back up without knowing next level?)
```

Has anyone worked this out? I'd just use nested output and avoid applying this logic to linear, but there are no "has-children" or "here" classes if it matches the current URL.

Thanks!

Mark

**UPDATE** This is where I started. I've been playing with depthX_start and depthX_end and am still seeing this spot where depth3_ends and it doesn't back up to depth1. So my next depth1 category is at level 2 in the UL.

```
        <ul>
        {exp:gwcode_categories group_id="3" style="linear"}
            <li class="{if has_children}has-children{/if} {if cat_url_title=='{freebie_2}'}here{/if}"><a href="/{segment_1}/{cat_url_title}">{cat_name}</a>{if has_children}
                <ul>{/if}
                {if depth2_end OR depth3_end OR depth4_end}
            </li></ul>{/if}
            {if !has_children}</li>{/if}
        {/exp:gwcode_categories}
        </ul>
```

You'll see the classes I need to add there. We're using JavaSript to enable expand/collpase on a given item, and to trigger the left nav to open where .here is.

Comment: Mark, can you post the current code? Also, do you want the entire list to expand/collapse from each depth1 parent or expand the parent of the current page?

Comment: If that code isn't quite right, I'm not so worried about the per-item opening/closing tag logic as I am closing off a gap of 2+ levels. I.e., depth3 -> depth1. That's what's tripping me up. The ultimate goal is just to get those two classes on the list items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it seems the logic works when the nesting drops back 1 parent, but breaks when the parents drop back two levels or more. After testing this on my end, it looks the `depthX_end` variables are all fired at the same time in the loop–so you will need a condition to test when the list drops back two parents or more.

```
<ul>
{exp:gwcode_categories group_id="3" style="linear"}
   <li class="{if has_children}has-children{/if} {if cat_url_title=='{freebie_2}'}here{/if}"><a href="/{segment_1}/{cat_url_title}">{cat_name} - {if depth1_end}1{/if}{if depth2_end}2{/if}{if depth3_end}3{/if} {if depth4_end}4{/if}</a>
   {if has_children}<ul>{/if}
   {if depth2_end OR depth3_end OR depth4_end}</li></ul>{/if}
   {if depth1_end AND depth2_end AND depth3_end}</li></ul>{/if}
   {if depth1_end AND depth2_end AND depth3_end AND depth4_end}</li></ul>{/if}
   {if !has_children}</li>{/if}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
</ul>
```